# Firebase email user authentication

Tags: java

`I'm trying to extract emails dynamically from the user to create accounts but Firebase keeps returning an email error... I was wondering whether it is possible to extract emails dynamically or you have to hard code the emails and password.

```
final EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_email);
    final String newEmail = email.getText().toString();
    final EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_password);
    final String newPass = password.getText().toString();
    final EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.full_name);
    final String userName = username.getText().toString();


 @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            rootRef.createUser(newEmail,newPass,new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String,Object>>(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String,Object> result){
                    rootRef.child("users").child(userName).child("User Name").setValue(userName);
                    rootRef.authWithPassword(newEmail,newPass,new Firebase.AuthResultHandler(){
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData){
                            Intent a = new Intent(CreateAccount.this,userHome.class);
                            startActivity(a);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError){
                            text1.setText("An error occurred.Please try again");
                        }
                    });
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError){
                    Fragment createAccount = new Fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.sign_up_fail,createAccount).commit();
                    switch (firebaseError.getCode()){
                        case FirebaseError.EMAIL_TAKEN:
                            text1.setText("That Email is already taken");
                            break;
                        case FirebaseError.INVALID_EMAIL:
                            text1.setText("That Email is invalid");
                            break;
                        case FirebaseError.NETWORK_ERROR:
                            text1.setText("Network Error.Check your connection.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could have posted which error Firebase returns.

You don't have to hardcode emails or password, check their tutorial page for android user authentication: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html

*EDIT*

Here is a sample from personal code that might help you.

```
referencia.createUser(email.getText().toString(), senha.getText().toString(), new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result)
```

I currently use this on a fully functional app. If yours isn't working you could send your error message.

Comment: In the guides they add the emails by writing in the actual email like :

Comment: like : ref.authWithPassword{"example@example.com","passwordexample",Firebase.ValueResultHandler<map<String,Object>>(){...}}

Comment: The input is a string, you have to treat it as you would any text area.

Comment: No problem! If you could check the answer as correct, it'd be helpful to me.